# Line follower robot using max 8 NAND gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

So I have to figure out the logic for a line follower robot using at maximum 8 NAND gates (2 7400HC series NAND circuits).

The robot has 3 sensors, which give 1 on a black surface and 0 on a white surface. The robot has 2 motors, one on the left and one on the right.

Below is the truth table I have made. A, B and C for the individual sensors. "LM" for Left Motor and "RM" for Right Motor.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
A& B & C & LM & RM \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ \hline
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1\\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\ \hline
\end{array}

My aim is that the robot tries to get the black line either under sensor "B" or when the line is wide enough, under all sensors.

Next i made the K-Maps for both motors. Left motor first.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 LM&  & AB \\ \hline
 && 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
 C& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
\end{array}(Sorry for the scuffed K-map)

From which I got the function

> F=C+A´B

Then the K-Map for the right motor.

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 RM&& AB &  \\ \hline
 && 00 & 01 & 11 & 10 \\ \hline
 C&0& 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\ \hline
 &1& 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ \hline
\end{array}

And the function

> F=BC'+AC'+AB

I have two main problems.

1. How do I use De Morgans laws to convert these functions to use NAND gates only? I don't quite understand them.
2. How do I combine these two boolean functions? Does that come naturally after converting the individual functions to use NAND gates?

Answer (score 1):

Using [Logic Friday 1](https://logic-friday.software.informer.com/1.1/), I generated three solutions:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Sadly, none of them fits in two `4 x NAND2` ICs.

Is it possible to revise the truth table to make it simpler?
What purpose do the three sensors have?

Comment: Yes, by changing the fifth row to LM=1 and RM=1 it made the boolean functions much simpler. This allowed me to create the circuit I needed with 8 NAND gates.